# Cycle for animation made with GSAP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I have 3 pictures. They are changing with animation.

With GSAP I want to make the animation cycle which will repeat several times(5, 6 or 7 for example). I used the method .restart(), but it doest work correctly. I call this method after the third picture disappears, but then the cycle begins from the second picture and some animations doesn't work. So I dont know what to do. Please, help me :(

In simple terms, I have 3 pictures, which change with rotation, scale and opacity in order. After the third picture is fade out I want to repeat my animation similarly (with rotation, scale and opacity in order). So my problem is to make the cycle to do this.

HTML:

```
<div align="center">
    <img id ="image" src="http://s1.1zoom.me/b4445/4/Planets_Nebulae_in_space_518424_240x400.jpg" width="240px" height="400px">
    <img id ="image1" src="http://www.mobi-city.ru/wallpaper/image/nature_13_240x400.jpg" width="240px" height="400px">
    <img id ="image2" src="http://m.chromesphere.net/Finals/chromesphere/chromesphere_i900_240x400.jpg" width="240px" height="400px">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image, #image1, #image2 {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
}

div {
    width: 100%;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#image").css("display", "block");
var image = document.getElementById('image');
var image1 = document.getElementById('image1');
var image2 = document.getElementById('image2');

    var tl = new TimelineLite({
        delay: 2,
        onComplete: function() {
            $("#image").css("display", "none");
            $("#image1").css("display", "block");
            TweenLite.fromTo(image1, 1, {scale: 0, opacity: 0}, {scale: 1, opacity: 1, delay: 0})

                            var tl_1 = new TimelineLite({
                            delay: 2,
                            onComplete: function() {
                                $("#image1").css("display", "none");
                                $("#image2").css("display", "block");
                                TweenLite.fromTo(image2, 1, {scale: 0, opacity: 0}, {scale: 1, opacity: 1, delay: 0})

                                                var tl_2 = new TimelineLite({
                                                delay: 2,
                                                onComplete: function () {
                                                    alert("done");
                                                    tl.restart();
                                                }
                                                });

                                                tl_2.add(TweenLite.to(image2, 1, {scale: 0, opacity: 0, ease: Back.easeIn}), 1);
                                                tl_2.add(TweenLite.to(image2, 2, {x: 0, rotation: 360, ease: Power1.easeInOut}), 0);




                                }
                            });

                    tl_1.add(TweenLite.to(image1, 1, {scale: 0, opacity: 0, ease: Back.easeIn}), 1);
                    tl_1.add(TweenLite.to(image1, 2, {x: 0, rotation: 360, ease: Power1.easeInOut}), 0);

        }
    });

    tl.add(TweenLite.to(image, 1, {scale: 0, opacity: 0, ease: Back.easeIn}), 1);
    tl.add(TweenLite.to(image, 2, {x: 0, rotation: 360, ease: Power1.easeInOut}), 0);
```

CodePen:

https://codepen.io/syncmaxim/pen/ZMexPZ?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was very difficult for me to understand what you were trying to do but I'm pretty sure your code was far more complicated than it needed to be. I took a guess at the type of effect you were going for, and created this codepen: 
https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/LJxgBv?editors=0010

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img"),
    delayTime = 2,
    animationTime = 1,
    tl = new TimelineMax({repeat:-1, delay:animationTime + delayTime, repeatDelay:delayTime});

TweenMax.set(images, {autoAlpha:0, scale:0});
//animate the first image in (don't put this in the timeline because it's different - there's no image showing behind it!)
TweenMax.to(images[0], animationTime, {autoAlpha:1, scale:1});

//now loop through the rest of the images and build their animations
for (var i = 1; i < images.length; i++) {
  tl.to(images[i], animationTime, {autoAlpha:1, scale:1}, (i-1) * (animationTime + delayTime));
  //after the new image animates in, we can hide the old one that's behind it (aids browser performance)
  tl.set(images[i-1], {autoAlpha:0, scale:0});
}

//now take the FIRST image and change the zIndex so that it's ON TOP of the last image, and animate it in. 
tl.fromTo(images[0], animationTime, {zIndex:100}, {autoAlpha:1, scale:1, delay:delayTime, immediateRender:false});
```

Hopefully it's easy to tweak things to get what you need. I added comments to help explain what's going on.

If you have GSAP-related questions, feel free to post them in the dedicated forums at https://greensock.com/forums. It'd be best if you could provide a sample codepen that demonstrates the issue - that makes troubleshooting much faster.

Happy tweening!

Comment: yes, that is what I need. now i understand why i have problems with displaying my second and third image. your comment helped me with this problem.

But why you used zIndex and visibility:hidden instead of display: none ?

Comment: I used visibility:hidden for several reasons: 1) it performs better because it avoids document reflow, 2) I assumed that you wanted the old image to remain visible while the new one animates into place. The way you had it set up with toggling display:none|block, they probably wouldn't overlap (depending on other CSS). I had to alter the z-index on that very last part so that the bottom image would jump to the top when it transitions in (otherwise you wouldn't see it underneath the last image). Happy tweening!

Answer (score 1):

the first image you are hiding in the first iteration and when you return you do not show it again. Try showing it again before doing the reset, (display:block) something like this:

```
var tl_2 = new TimelineLite({
                delay: 2,
                onComplete: function() {
                    alert("done");
                    $("#image").css("display", "block"); 
                    tl.restart();
                }
            });
```

Comment: yes, thanks, it works, but animation still works incorrect and i dont know how to fix it :(